# Tool to glue dozen of PNG into video

Tags: video

I have made nearly 20 PNG screen captures. I wish to glue them into video. Could you recommend a tool?

Better if that would be smooth change from one picture to another, like tween motion in Flash.

Using actual flash is not an option. Because tool must be free and run on linux.

Comment: use after effects or any video editing package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [mplayer's](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) mencoder:

```
for i in *.png; do for j in `seq 1 20`; do echo $i; done; done > frames.txt
mencoder mf://@frames.txt -mf fps=5:type=png \
  -audiofile audio.mp3 -oac copy \
  -of lavf -ovc lavc \
  -lavcopts vcodec=flv:mbd=2:v4mv:mv0:trell:cbp:last_pred=3:vbitrate=200 \
  -lavfopts i_certify_that_my_video_stream_does_not_use_b_frames \
  -o video.flv
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
i_certify... is this a joke?

Comment: No, it isn't. It was required when I used it - without it I got an error from mencoder requesting adding it.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it with wierd option i got error, w/o option it produced empty flv. :(

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

1. Install ffmpeg.
2. Create your pngs with a continuous number in the file name, e.g. img0001.png, img0002.png, …, …img5467.png.
3. Then run ffmpeg -qscale 5 -r 20 -b 9600 -i img%04d.png movie.mp4

Thanks to:
http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2008/04/28/create-a-movie-file-from-single-image-files-png-jpegs/

Comment: Guys, the reported link helps understanding the meaning of the flags. In the specific, the video resulting out of the command that Will posted here might be a bit too slow. Try with "-r 25" instead.

Answer (score 1):

[png2mng.pl](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/png2mng_pl) As you can guess from extension, it's a Perl script.

Comment: It's very interesting, it really produced mng, but now i don't know how to show it. :) Konqueror does not.

Comment: Hmm ideed interesting, Konqueror from KDE3 shows it. Konqueror from KDE4 does not. It's some bug in Qt4.

Comment: Thanks, vartec, i'll try one from KDE3.

Answer (score 1):

Although, the question is already answered long time ago, for future reference, it has been asked again in the past and contains a beautiful answer that helped me as well:

[How can I script the creation of a movie from a set of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945250/how-can-i-script-the-creation-of-a-movie-from-a-set-of-images)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) - I've used its "image2" codec to turn an mpeg into a series of JPEG frames, pretty sure the reverse is possible. If it can't read PNG you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to convert your PNGs to JPEG first.

Answer (score -1):

Video Mach [(http://www.gold-software.com/download8598.html)](http://www.gold-software.com/download8598.html) seems to be a good option for you. Although for winows, its a shareware.

-AD