# Create video from nearly still images

Tags: image, video

I make a set of pictures of landscape from nearly same point and direction, one photo each day for three months.
Is there a way for creating video from this image set which can run smooth?
I need some like this question ([How can I script the creation of a movie from a set of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945250/how-can-i-script-the-creation-of-a-movie-from-a-set-of-images)) but with noise/vibration reduction filter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) which has the ability to open a image sequence, it also has the option to define pre compression filters, I know it has the noise filter not sure about vibration (but you can always add your own filters).

After you open the image sequence and define the filters, you can use what ever install VCM codec that you have on the machine to create the movie.

Comment: Thank you!

As I know, noise filter is for removing noise from static images but I am looking for filter that find-and-snap common points on series of images then create smooth video. 
Some like Panorama Maker* soft, tile images not side-by-side but in video stream.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on how to ["Make movies from image files"](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/). This is with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: This guide is for simply joining computer-generated images, but I search for tremor reduction filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the GNU Image Manipulation Program,  [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: @unknown (google), Apologies for this distraction, but you have a message from Chuck on your Python reference to my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943153/converting-an-excel-xls-file-to-a-comma-separated-csv-file-without-the-gui

Comment: There is a GIME time-lapse animation reference at http://www.timelapseforum.com/time-lapse-animated-gifs-and-videos-t44.html, though not the find-and-snap common points trick that you want.

Comment: Sorry, GIMP reference not contain any noise-reduction-step :(